# Foreign key constraint - how to delete referenced record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I stumbled across a problem, which is very basic, thus didn't really think it through.

I have two tables, let's say:

```
Table1: col1 PK,
Table2: col1 FK references Table1(col1)
```

When I want to delete record from `Table1`, which is referenced by record in `Table2`, SQL would throw error, that `DELETE` statement coflicted with a constraint. Which is understandable and desired behaviour.

What if I really want to delete the row and set reference in `Table2` to `NULL`  in all rows referencing key being deleted?

I know that I can do it manually - set references in `Table2` to `NULL` and then delete. But is there more concise way?

Comment: What can be more concise than a single UPDATE statement to null out the foreign references in `Table2`?  This seems like a completely viable option to me.

Comment: I was expecting to set some option of some sort to specify behavior in such delete statement. You are right, that it's conise enough to execute `update` and `delete` statement. But I am just curious... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could configure Insert and Update Specification rule by setting `Set Null` option on FK relationship. I have attached an image from Sql Server Management Studio. Also, there is a useful article [here.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/)

[image]

Comment: Great. Both, you answer and the source!

Answer (score 3):

You can alter your database structure by adding a delete rule, `set to null` OR `onDeleteCascade`

Comment: This would delete referencing records. That's not what I want.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn you can specify ON CASCADE SET NULL or SET DEFAULT

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer as an alternative which actually gets around the need to even null out the foreign key references in `Table2`.  You may consider performing *soft* deletion on the records in `Table1`.  What this means is that you would maintain a new column `deleted` which would be set to true if the record is logically deleted.

The advantage of this method is that you may leave all the child records in `Table2` completely intact, including their references.  But logically speaking, the record in `Table1` could be treated as deleted.  This is not an option if space be a concern, e.g. if you really need to remove records from your tables.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Interesting points, but that's not exactly what I needed :)